# I want to make a google doc a place where I can drop code that will automatically update on a web page

Tags: html, google-docs

As an example, say I have an image on my page that I need to change every week.  Instead of going into the code and changing the picture, I'd like to somehow put a reference to specific cell in a "published to web" google doc in place of my image in the code so I can just change the name of the image in the google doc and the new image will show up on my webpage.  I want to accomplish this so I can have several people (who can't code) be able to change the image from their computers.  I know it's possible, but I don't even know where to start.  Anyone know how to set this up this?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, when you `File > Publish to the web`, Google Docs will generate an iframe embed code that looks something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopq/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

You can insert the iframe into your webpage. You can check on "Automatically republish when changes are made" so your users would just need to modify the document when they need to change the image.

However, I'd highly recommend that **using a proper CMS would be much better**, or at least build a rough authentication and CRUD to update the image.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't want visitors to actually see the google doc, I just want to use it as a tool to edit the page.  So say I have a piece of code like `<img src="images/example.jpg" width="400" height="618" />`.  If I could change it to `<img src="google doc cell A1" width="400" height="618" />` then I could have anyone log into google, put the image link in cell A1 and that image will change on the webpage.

I would love to set up a CMS, but it's way out of my abilities and it's for a small business so I don't think the cash is there to go that far.

Any ideas?  Thanks again